# Why is the html input type="datetime-local" value of YEAR 7 chars long?

Tags: html, datetime, input, tags

Im have to do a Website-Project and i will use the input type "datetime-local" to choose a date+time.
When i write some Numbers in it, the YEAR will always have 7 characters (instead of 4).

How can i change this?

Greetings

Comment: Where's your code? I get a four-digit year.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`. Note that "T" is literally "T". More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Answer (score 7):

HTML specification doesn't define the upper limit of dates for `<input type=datetime-local>`. However, ECMA Script defines the upper limit of `Date` object.  It's September 13 275,760.

You can set the upper limit in your HTML, and Google Chrome shrinks the year field if it's less than 6 digits.

```
<input type="datetime-local" max="9999-12-31T23:59">
```